# Accessing Nested Field Values javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying access accounts -> posts -> message with a for loop but I'm not sure how to write the dot annotation for accessing the nested field values. With the code below I receive the first field value for accounts -> posts -> message but I want to be able to access all instances of message for all posts under the account. Thank you.

```
FB.api(
'/me',
'GET',
{"fields":"accounts{posts{message,permalink_url,picture,created_time}}"},
function(response) {
  console.log('GET accounts completed');
  console.log(response);
    var list = document.getElementById('status');   

    for (var i=0; i < response.accounts.data.length; i++) {
            console.log('FOR Loop completed');
            var li = document.createElement('li');  
            li.style.listStyle = 'none';

            li.innerHTML = response.accounts.data[i].posts.data[i].message; 
            list.appendChild(li);

    }

}
);
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `console.log(response)` please? If you can attach a screen capture of it then even better.

Answer (score 0):

It's not hard, use a for loop again for the `posts.data`.

```
for (var i=0; i < response.accounts.data.length; i++) {
        console.log('FOR Loop completed');
        var li = document.createElement('li');  
        li.style.listStyle = 'none';

        var posts = response.accounts.data[i].posts.data;
        for (var j = 0; j < posts.length; j++) {
            li.innerHTML = posts[j].message; 
            list.appendChild(li);
        }
}
```